# React - implementing a search by key words to list of items in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-component

I am building a search page using react. below is my search component which I try to search  the below albums by such as, an album name, user ID, tags and title of the image/video.

I have created search component and album component and component for listing albums

I would like to know how to link search component and album listing component to filter the albums when typing search.

> Note - there are two search fields here, first one is for search and
>   second one is for different search. Here I am referring only to the
>   first search input tag

if anyone knows please check.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Nav,
  Navbar,
  Collapse,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  NavbarToggler,
  DropdownToggle,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Config from '../../../constants/config';
import { SidebarNavItems } from '../Sidebar';
import logoImages from '../../../images/logo.png';

require('./styles.scss');

        class Search extends Component {
                  constructor() {
                    super();
                    this.inputNames = ['input1', 'input2'];
                    this.state = {
                      hiddenInputs: {
                        input1: { hidden: false, first: true },
                        input2: { hidden: true, first: false },
                      },
                      expanded: false,
                    };
                  }

                  handleClick(name) {
                    const hI = Object.assign({}, this.state.hiddenInputs);
                    let expanded = this.state.expanded;

                    if (expanded && hI[name].first === true) {

                      expanded = false;
                    } else if (expanded) {
                      expanded = false;
                      this.inputNames.forEach((input) => {
                        const isSame = input === name;
                        hI[input].first = isSame;
                        hI[input].hidden = !isSame;
                      });
                    } else {
                      expanded = true;
                    }
                    this.setState({ expanded, hiddenInputs: hI });
                  }

                  render() {
                    const { input1, input2 } = this.state.hiddenInputs;
                    const { expanded } = this.state;
                    const clsName1 = `myInput${input1.hidden && !expanded ? ' hidden' : ''}${input1.first ? ' first' : ' second'}`;
                    const clsName2 = `myInput${input2.hidden && !expanded ? ' hidden' : ''}${input2.first ? ' first' : ' second'}`;
                    return (
                      <div className="search_bar">
                        <div className="input-container flex">
                           // this is the search tag I'm using to here. the below tag is for another  functionality
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Type a keyword " onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'input1')} className={clsName1} />
                          <input type="password" placeholder="Type " onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'input2')} className={clsName2} />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                }

                export default withRouter(Search);
```

---

> these are individual albums which I want to filter

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Card, CardBody, CardTitle, CardHeader, CardFooter,
} from 'reactstrap';
import FollowButton from '../buttons/FollowButton';
import ThumbnailSlider from './ThumbnailSlider';

import noImageSrc from '../../../images/no-image.png';

require('./styles.scss');

const AlbumCard = ({ album }) => (
  <Card className="albummain">
    <CardHeader>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-8 d-flex align-items-center">
          <a
            href="link"
            title=""
          >
            <img
              src={
                Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(album.user, 'profile_picture')
                  ? album.user.profile_picture.imgurlhere
                  : 'imglink'
              }
              className="rounded-circle img-fluid"
              alt="user name goes here"
            />
          </a>
          <div className="d-flex flex-fill flex-column">
            <div className="user-name-item">
              {album.user.alias_name !== 'undefined'
                ? album.user.alias_name
                : `${album.user.first_name} ${album.user.last_name}`}
            </div>
            <div className="date-item">
20 hours ago
            </div>
          </div>
          <FollowButton size="sm" className="follow-button" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4 d-none d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div className="d-flex flex-column">
            <i className="fas fa-eye" />
            {album.statistic.view}
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex flex-column">
            <i className="far fa-thumbs-up" />
            {album.statistic.likes}
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex flex-column">
            <i className="fas fa-comments" />
            {album.statistic.comments}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </CardHeader>
    <img
      className="img-top"
      src={
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(album.picture, 'img url')
          ? album.picture.img url
          : noImageSrc
      }
      alt="title"
    />
    <CardBody>
        {album.title}
      </CardTitle> */}
      <div className="thumbnail-slider">
        <ThumbnailSlider thumbnails={album.thumbs} />
      </div>
    </CardBody>
    <CardFooter className="nothing">
just Footer
    </CardFooter>
  </Card>
);

AlbumCard.propTypes = {
  album: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
};

export default AlbumCard;
```

> this is the main components which loads albums inside

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import Card from './Card';
import Error from '../Error';

const AlbumsListing = ({ error, loading, albums }) => {
  // Error
  if (error) return <Error content={error} />;

  // Build Cards for Listing
  const cards = albums.map(item => <Card album={item} key={`${item.id}`} />);

  // Show Listing
  return (
    <div className="albums-list-container">
      <Row className={loading ? 'content-loading' : ''}>
        <Col sm="12" className="card-columns">
          {cards}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};

AlbumsListing.propTypes = {
  error: PropTypes.string,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  albums: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape()).isRequired,
};

AlbumsListing.defaultProps = {
  error: null,
};

export default AlbumsListing;
```

thanks..

Comment: where you're using search component?

Comment: @AbhaySehgal search component is inside header component

Comment: your header component and AlbumListing component have same parent?, you should use redux which will provide application level state then you can directly filter album list from search component else you have to pass the search string to albumlisting component to filter the array which will make your code more complex

Comment: @AbhaySehgal  thanks for the reply . yes header and album listing all inside components folder.  I am using a stater kit, i think it has redux already set up.  i am suing this kit https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-kit. can you please check and is redux already there and can I use it directly ?

Comment: Yes, it has redux you can include it in your code

Comment: @AbhaySehgal Hi, if possible please message me in my Gmail fei075293 at gmail.com. I would like to discuss something regarding this project, thank you